# how can you have layers see through each other on a web page

Tags: html, css

i am trying to understand [how you can do something like this](http://www.housingworks.org/) site where the pictures show through the top menu.  is this done through css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that is accomplished by using a PNG image file, which supports transparencies... If you look at the markup and CSS for that page, you'll find this [file](http://www.housingworks.org/i/screen/bg-header-long.png) being used in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a [simple CSS attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp)

Edit: someone has pointed out that they've made use of transparent images.  However, if you look at their stylesheets, they have *also* used the opacity attribute, and using CSS is a much *better* way to do it.  One line in a stylesheet vs however many transparent images saves you hosting space, bandwidth, and decreases page load time.

Comment: All three of the answers using the W3School link is wrong. It's most certainly *not* using the `opacity` property here`. Additionally, linking to *that* horrid site is a pretty bad idea regardless of whether or not the property in question here is correct

Comment: He asked how you could do something *like* this.  And he got three answers referencing **the** standard method for doing it.  If you don't like our link, make yourself useful and post a better one instead of complaining.

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved using the opacity filter. See [Css Image Transeparency](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the opacity property. For more info: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp